# how to make background image slidein when text slides out

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Here I am trying to show the image as background when all my text lines slideout.When the text lines are sliding out then the image should slide in.But my image is not being displayed after text is slideout.

http://jsbin.com/fujiwufina/edit?html,css,output

Thank you.

Comment: You don't seem to have any slide animation on the background image. The container has only a opacity and visibility change.

Comment: I have used animation for container imageslidein using keyframes.

Comment: That's the one I was referring to. It has no slide in animation (though you've named it as one). It only has an opacity and visibility change.